# Create column with running total amount with conditions in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with 'account', 'order_date' and 'amount' columns.

[image]

I need to create column "balance" based on the conditions. The tricky part here is current row in "balance" column depends on the previous row of  same column which is being created.

Here is Logical explanation:

if amount > 0 then

```
  amount + [Row-1:balance]
```

else

```
min([Row-1:balance],0) + amount
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: I did try one solution with case statements using spark-sql, but the solution's performance is terrible while running on whole dataset with 22 million records.

Comment: FYI, here [Row-1:balance] meaning, calculated previous row value of 'balance' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas UDF (Spark >= 2.3)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import datetime as dt

        data = [
            {'account': '1', 'order_date': '11/18/20', 'amount': -34.99},
            {'account': '1', 'order_date': '10/28/20', 'amount': -4.99},
            {'account': '1', 'order_date': '9/11/20', 'amount': 4.99},
            {'account': '1', 'order_date': '9/2/20', 'amount': 9.98}]
        # For simiplicity, creating a new column "balance" with 0.0 
        input_df = self._spark.createDataFrame(data).withColumn('balance', f.lit(0.0))
        input_df.show()
        schema = input_df.schema

        @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
        def _get_running_total(input: pd.DataFrame):
            import os
            # To fix a bug in pyarrow newer versions
            os.environ['ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT'] = "1" 
            previous_balance = None
            input['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(input['order_date'])
            df = input.sort_values(by=['order_date'], ascending=False)
            df['order_date'] = df['order_date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))
            for i, row in df.iterrows():
                current_amount = row['amount']
                if i == 0:
                    running_total = current_amount
                else:
                    if current_amount > 0:
                        running_total = current_amount + previous_balance
                    else:
                        if previous_balance > 0:
                            previous_balance = 0
                        running_total = previous_balance + current_amount
                df._set_value(i, 'balance', running_total)
                previous_balance = running_total
            return df
        input_df.groupby('account').apply(_get_running_total).show()
```

**Updated, run fine on 3.2**

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import datetime as dt
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


_spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()  

data = [
    {'account': '1', 'order_date': '11/18/20', 'amount': -34.99},
    {'account': '1', 'order_date': '10/28/20', 'amount': -4.99},
    {'account': '1', 'order_date': '9/11/20', 'amount': 4.99},
    {'account': '1', 'order_date': '9/2/20', 'amount': 9.98}]
# For simiplicity, creating a new column "balance" with 0.0 
input_df = _spark.createDataFrame(data).withColumn('balance', f.lit(0.0))
input_df.show()
schema = input_df.schema

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _get_running_total(input: pd.DataFrame):
    import os
    # To fix a bug in pyarrow newer versions
    os.environ['ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT'] = "1" 
    previous_balance = None
    input['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(input['order_date'])
    df = input.sort_values(by=['order_date'], ascending=False)
    df['order_date'] = df['order_date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        current_amount = row['amount']
        if i == 0:
            running_total = current_amount
        else:
            if current_amount > 0:
                running_total = current_amount + previous_balance
            else:
                if previous_balance > 0:
                    previous_balance = 0
                running_total = previous_balance + current_amount
        df._set_value(i, 'balance', running_total)
        previous_balance = running_total
    return df

input_df.groupby('account').apply(_get_running_total).show()
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Here you are only sorting the records since you took only one account, we should group the records on account and then sort within each group using order_date, we should apply this logic for each group of records.

Comment: @Anand - the sorting is already happening within the UDF before calculating the running total for each group/account. please check!

Comment: its in last line, got it. Thanks @veerat

Comment: This worked totally fine with minimal changes. Appreciate your time on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Windowing & spark lag function?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

sc = SparkContext(appName="PRowDiffApp")
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 65), (2, 66), (3, 65), (4, 68), (5, 71)])

df = sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "value"])

my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id")

df = df.withColumn("prev_value", F.lag(df.value).over(my_window))
df = df.withColumn("diff", F.when(F.isnull(df.value - df.prev_value), 0)
                              .otherwise(df.value - df.prev_value))

df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did try Window and lag function in several different ways, I have googled much of the information available, but couldn't resolve this totally. If we get solid working solution, that would be great.